# Login system for CodeIgniter 3.0

Tags: php, authentication, frameworks, login-script, codeigniter-3

I am looking for **simple** and easy to use/install **login system for** **CodeIgniter 3.0 (dev)**.

I've seen few different scripts but mostly for CodeIgniter 2.x.

I will appreciate any help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The best Auth library out there is [Ion-Auth by Ben Edmunds](https://github.com/benedmunds/CodeIgniter-Ion-Auth)

From the repo page:

```
CodeIgniter Version 3 Compatibility

CodeIgniter v3 requires the class names to be ucfirst(). In order to support this follow the standard installation procedures and then either rename the following files or create symlinks

config/ion_auth.php               =>   config/Ion_auth.php
models/ion_auth_model.php         =>   models/Ion_auth_model.php
models/ion_auth_mongodb_model.php =>   models/Ion_auth_mongodb_model.php
```

Note: Ion-Auth is implemented in many projects. Like PyroCMS.

Comment: Thank you. I've installed Ion-Auth and everything works fine, however this is powerfull solution not simple ;-)